# What kind of paint should I use to paint a field stone foundation wall?

Tags: walls, painting, foundation, stone

I have a 1900 house with a field stone foundation. The foundation is in good shape. There is minimal moisture. I want to paint the walls to make it look nicer. What kind of paint should I be using?
I will be spraying on.

Comment: see also: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33201/how-can-i-reduce-or-eliminate-flaking-from-a-limestone-basement/39634#39634

Answer (score 1):

Don't!

"Painting a stone wall to make it look nicer" is "good" for a few months, perhaps. Forever after, it's a mess.

Stone walls don't need paint, don't benefit from paint, and look like [bleep] when the paint peels. Removing the parts of the paint that don't peel is difficult, so they look like [bleep] ever after.

Don't go down this road. Your house will look much better, as it has for 117 years.

Comment: And that moisture that doesn't exist in the wall will push the paint right off.  Absolutely right, it will just look horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Ecnerwal. However, if you insist, there is a primer called masonry primer, or concrete bonding primer. It can be sprayed with a pretty open tip, just see what the label suggests. That will allow you to topcoat with any exterior latex you should choose.